# Reduce Javascript array of objects to just object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a javascript array of object like this

```
let Object  = [
   {"Form Factor": "2.5 inch"},
   {"Capacity": "1 TB"},
   {"Memory Components": "NAND 3"}
]
```

i want to reduce it to just an object like this

```
resultObject = {
  "Form Factor" : "2.5 Inch",
  "Capacity": "1 TB",
  "Memory Components" : "NAND 3"
}
```

Comment: So did you try using `.reduce`? What happened?

Answer (score 3):

You could spread the objects and assign them to a new object.

```js
const
    array  = [{ "Form Factor": "2.5 inch" }, { "Capacity": "1 TB" }, { "Memory Components": "NAND 3" }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array);

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data  = [
   {"Form Factor": "2.5 inch"},
   {"Capacity": "1 TB"},
   {"Memory Components": "NAND 3"}
]

const result=data.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
const keys=Object.keys(curr)
acc[keys[0]]=curr[keys[0]]
 return acc;
},{});

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```